# A limit of $f(x)\ln(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Consider a real $\alpha>0$ and a function $\phi$ defined in $(-\alpha,\alpha)$ satisfying $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to0}\phi(x)=0}$. Does $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to0}\phi(x)\ln(x)}$ exists?

We know that if $\phi$ is differentiable at $0$ then the limit exists and its value is $0$ since $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to0}\phi(x)\ln(x)}= \displaystyle{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\phi(x)}x\times x\ln(x)=\phi’(0)\times 0=0}$.

But if we suppose that $\phi$ not necessarily differentiable is there a way to find this limit?

I guessed that the limit does not necessarily exist but I could not find a counter example.

Tried $\phi(x)=x^r$ where $r$ is positive rational number, in that case the limit is 0.

Also tried $\phi(x)=x\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)$ but $|\phi(x)\ln(x)|\le |x\ln(x)|$ and also 0.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(x)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln(x)}$, then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\phi(x)=0$ but $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\phi(x)\ln(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does not exist.

Comment: Your $\phi$ is not well defined in $(-\alpha,\alpha)$

Comment: @DINEDINE look at $\phi(|x|)$ or $\phi(x^2)$ then. Whether $\phi(x)$ is defined in a symmetric interval isn't really important since $\ln x$ is only defined for $x > 0$ anyways.

Comment: There is no point in defining $\phi(x)$ for $x<0$ because $\ln$ is only defined on $(0,+\infty)$ (you can however extend the definition of $\phi$ with $\phi(x)=\phi(-x)$ for $x<0$). To define $\phi$ at $x=0$, we can still impose $\phi(0)=0$ and there $\phi$ is even continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Get that! Killing my self to find a kind of mysterious function. Merci beaucoup!!!